nuxt.js error: ('<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON)
I'm new to the web, I made a page with a form for entering name and password, but when I try to get data, instead of json I get an html page and an error '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON. Also, my data should be saved in cookies by credentials: 'include', but this is not happening and I don’t understand why. I'm using nuxt.js and creating an 'spa' project. Please help me if you now where i'm doing wrong.
My script for page login.vue:
 <script>
    export default {
       name: 'login',
       data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            password: ''
        }
       },
       
       methods: {
        async submit() {
            const jsn = JSON.stringify({
                name: this.name,
                password: this.password
            });
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
            body: jsn
          });

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            await this.$router.push('/');
        }
       }
    }
    </script>

I'm tried to replace headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} to headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} but didn't help to solve problem. Now I understand that the error occurs because I am receiving an html page instead of json, but don't now why this happens.

http://localhost:3000/api/login - it's yours api? if so add it's code to answer

I already find an answer for this issue! But now i feel really stupid, so i doing this project using video tutorial but didnt't mention that i need a server logic that work with url request http://localhost:3000/api/login. So the solve was to create this backend server that return json answer!
P.S. Maybe i help someone with same problem)
